# Jenkins SCM Sync Configuration Plugin not working

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I installed SCM Sync configuration plugin. I created repository to keep backups of jenkins jobs.
In the created jobs, in bookmark Source Code Management I gave Repository URL and Credentials.
After job which has been succeeded I haven't seen any commits in repository.
Only this alert appeared in the bottom right corner: "SCM Sync status : Wed May 11 10:53:34 EDT 2016 : Error while checking in file to scm repository."
I set loggers in jenkins just like it is said here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScmSyncConfig+Troubleshootings
but noone appears. I made it the same as it is described in step: "Ensure you can access your Scm repository from Jenkins".
I set the personal/private key called "id_rsa w home directory of the jenkins process owner".
I can edit /hudson.scm. :

```
<hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-DescriptorImpl plugin="subversion@2.5.7">
  <generation>1</generation>
  <mayHaveLegacyPerJobCredentials>false</mayHaveLegacyPerJobCredentials>
  <workspaceFormat>8</workspaceFormat>
  <validateRemoteUpToVar>false</validateRemoteUpToVar>
  <storeAuthToDisk>false</storeAuthToDisk>
</hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-DescriptorImpl>
```

but effect was the same. Build success, Error while checking in file to scm repository, no informations
in loggers.

Here i will paste what appears in the Console Output:

```
Building on master in workspace /home/tomcat/.jenkins/jobs/ScmSyncConfigurationTest/workspace
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@bitbucket.org:~~/jenkinsbackup.git
 > git init /home/tomcat/.jenkins/jobs/ScmSyncConfigurationTest/workspace # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:~~/jenkinsbackup.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:~~/jenkinsbackup.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:~~/jenkinsbackup.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:~~/jenkinsbackup.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:~~/jenkinsbackup.git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:~~/jenkinsbackup.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 82c782cf29258f58a630d0ce2728bf8c85d4e03d (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 82c782cf29258f58a630d0ce2728bf8c85d4e03d
 > git rev-list 82c782cf29258f58a630d0ce2728bf8c85d4e03d # timeout=10
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /usr/share/apache-tomcat-latest/temp/hudson1626031519696649678.sh
+ echo hello world
hello world
Finished: SUCCESS
```

If there is something I have skipped, I would appreciate your effort to help me giving any clues.

Comment: I couldn't ever get this plugin working either, but ultimately stopped trying to use it due to a bug in version in version 0.0.9. Once you restart jenkins, your entire jenkins site will just be a white screen, and you have to manually revert configurations to fix. It's not a minor issue.

Answer (score 0):

The main bug I had with [SCM Sync configuration plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin) was with jobs having whitespaces in their names: [issue JENKINS 24686](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24686).

It just got fixed in the 0.10.0 version ([released 7 hours ago](https://github.com/jenkinsci/scm-sync-configuration-plugin/releases/tag/scm-sync-configuration-0.0.10))

you could check if your specific issue persists with that new release.